# TSQLT Procedure calls fake table from another Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, tsqlt

Im trying to do some Tsqlt test, and I want to separate my data from the test.

So I have one Procedure with data :

```
alter PROCEDURE [Test_Calss].[test Data_Test]
AS
BEGIN
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'Sales.Customers';

INSERT INTO Sales.Customers(custid, companyname, contactname, contacttitle,    address, city, region, postalcode, country, phone, fax)
VALUES(1, N'Customer NRZBB', N'Allen, Michael', N'Sales Representative', N'teste Str. 0123', test', NULL, N'122', test', N'01-342789',  N'030-033456');
```

also I have another Procedure which I want to use the Fake Table in it :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Test_Calss].[test Count_Customer]
AS
BEGIN

EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'Sales.Customers';

DECLARE @testres INT; SET @testres = 91;

DECLARE @counter INT;
SELECT @counter = COUNT(*) FROM [Test_Calss].[test Data_Test];

      EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals @testres,@counter;

END;
```

I need the Fake Table from the first procedure [Test_Calss].[test Data_Test] to be called and tested in the second one. I tried with EXEC but it didn't work.

Any Idea how to call the table and its contant ?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to have a `SetUp` stored procedure in my `TestClass`. I use Test classes quite liberally (much like I do in C#) so that I might have more than one test class per stored procedure if I really needed to.

So in your case I would have:

```
create PROCEDURE [Test_Calss].[SetUp]
AS
BEGIN
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'Sales.Customers';

INSERT INTO Sales.Customers(custid, companyname, contactname, contacttitle,    address, city, region, postalcode, country, phone, fax)
VALUES(1, N'Customer NRZBB', N'Allen, Michael', N'Sales Representative', N'teste Str. 0123', test', NULL, N'122', test', N'01-342789',  N'030-033456')
go


create PROCEDURE [Test_Calss].[test Count_Customer]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @testres INT; SET @testres = 91;

DECLARE @counter INT;
SELECT @counter = COUNT(*) FROM Sales.Customer;

EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals @testres,@counter;

END;
go

exec tSQLt.RunTestClass 'Test_Calss';
```

tSQTt calls the `SetUp` stored procedure before each test in the `TestClass` so you can use to to prepare your common data.